# use time.sleep with webdriver

Tags: python, time, webdriver

I have a problem with time module in use with webdriver. I set time sleep for 3 second but sometime my internet connection will be slow and program miss the element and raise error.

```
'''
driver.get('exammple.com')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('example')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('example')
'''
```

how can I handle this problem??

Comment: Thats why sleep is very bad approach,use WebDriverWait.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some polling:

```
'''
driver.get('exammple.com')
found=False
while(not found):
   elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('example')
   if elem:
       found=True
found=False
while(not found):
   elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('example')
   if elem:
       found=True
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
delay = 3 # seconds
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 
 'IdOfMyElement')))
```